# Не могу получить доступ к коллекции set, через оператор точка

Tags: java, spring

Класс User

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.example.demo.entity.enums.ERole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;

@Data
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, updatable = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String bio;

    @Column(length = 3000)
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ERole.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<ERole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH: mm:ss")
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Transient
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(Long id, String username, String email,
                String password,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * SECURITY
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Класс CustomUserDetailsService

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.entity.User;
import com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        return null;
    }

    public static User build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user. ВОТ ТУТ НЕ МОГУ
    }


}
```

Вот так нужно

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F7KE.png

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
```

а если роли нужны то

```
Set<ERole> roles = user.getRoles();
```